# How to retain space in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have an XML of the following process

```
<p>
  <author>
    <surname>John</surname> <given-name>Chen</given-name>
    <surname>Ram</surname> <given-name>Chen</given-name> 
    <surname>Raja</surname> <given-name>Singh</given-name> 
  </author>
</p>
```

Major problem is in space only. Space between surname and given-name, but after converting the file, space is gone. But I need retain space.

```
<p>
  <span class="author">
    <span class="surname">John</span> <span class="given-name">Chen</span>
    <span class="surname">Ram</span> <span class="given-name">Chen</span>
    <span class="surname">Raja</span> <span class="given-name">Singh</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Thanks for advance.

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="p span" />
<xsl:preserve-space elements="p span" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:element name="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="author|surname|given-name">
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? Some are known to use XML parsers that strip white space. You can try whether using `<p xml:space="preserve">...</p>` in the input helps. And you should certainly remove `<xsl:strip-space elements="p span" />` from your XSLT (well at least the `p`, `span` does not appear in your input so it should not matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be better if you insert space in stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="author"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:element name="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="author|surname|given-name">
    <xsl:element name="span">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First, strip all spaces inside `author` element `<xsl:strip-space elements="author"/>` for avoid duplication.

Second, insert single space `<xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>` between `<span class="surname">` and `<span class="given-name">`.